# pass static class's string constant into clientside code

Tags: asp.net

Passing a serverside variable into a client isn't anything too rough

```
var Variable = '<%= ServerVaraible %>'
```

where ServerVaraible is something accessible publicly in the codebehind, easy peasy

now lets say I have a Static Class as such

```
namespace Server.Helpers
{
   public static class QueryStringConstants
     {
       public static string CARID = "carId";
     }
}
```

Why can't I go:
    var Variable = '<%= Server.Helpers.QueryStringConstants.CARID %>'

if I do this i get an error saying

```
'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' does not contain a definition for 'Helpers' and no extension method 'Helpers' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' could be found
```

I am sure I am ment to be declaring something, but I am not 100% sure what......

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Server` represents a property that belongs to the class you're in (`Page`), so there's a naming conflict. To access your class avoiding the conflict, use the [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx) keyword, which forces you to use the full namespace:

```
var Variable = '<%= global::Server.Helpers.QueryStringConstants.CARID %>'
```

Comment: interesting. in trying to avoid a mega refactoring i prefer your solution to @Nicholas below, but using yours I now get a NullReferenceException on QueryStringConstants which is weird because it is a static class

Comment: `global::` is generally useful in naming conflict situations. You'll see it used often in auto-generated code, because when you use it, you're 100% guaranteed that you're referencing the type you want, with zero ambiguity or chance for conflict.

Comment: If you've posted your actual code, there's no way you'd get a `NullReferenceException` there - if you're seeing it, it's probably just giving you the wrong line in the debugger, and the exception really belongs to something else nearby. Take a look at the stacktrace on the exception.

Comment: i know right, thats why i was confused too. o wait, never mind, me just being stupid. its the next line throwing the error for somethign else. your solution saved the day. Thanks :)

Comment: Just as a side note - it's generally a good idea to go with better namespaces than something like `Server`. Typically your company name, so you can pretty much guarantee uniqueness. This is especially important when integrating with other libraries - suppose you added a reference to a DLL which also had a `Server.Helpers.QueryStringConstants` class (or a `Server.Helpers` class with a `QueryStringConstants` member) - your project would no longer compile.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rename your class from Server.Helpers to ServerTest.Helpers and could then access the value. I believe that the Server keyword is reserved, therefor when you go to call Server.Helpers it tries to find the Helpers class on the Server object which doesn't exist.